# Quel est le COD du verbe «donner» dans «(...)donner aux gens à qui il s'adresse l'impression qu'ils ne croient en rien» ?

Tags: compléments

C'est une phrase dans un article sur le site liberation.fr, voici le lien : http://www.liberation.fr/amphtml/tribune/2008/01/24/brisons-le-miroir_63377

> L'écrivain Jean-Marc Lenglen, par exemple, observait que cet oiseau «possède un art inégalé pour donner aux gens à qui il s'adresse l'impression qu'ils ne croient en rien.», l'art de discréditer non pas les convictions de l'adversaire, mais sa capacité même à avoir des convictions.

Dans cette phrase-là, je trouve qu'il n'existe pas de COD pour le verbe « donner », alors qu'est-ce qu'on donne aux gens ?

Pourquoi ne pas dire « pour donner aux gens l'impression qu'ils ne croient rien» ?

Par parenthèse, qu'est-ce que le mot « oiseau » désigne ? À mon avis, aucun oiseau est mentionné dans cet article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le COD est "l'impression qu'ils ne croient en rien". Il est placé après le COI "aux gens à qui il s'adresse".

Pour la parenthèse, "cet oiseau", que l'on trouve souvent sous la forme "ce drôle d'oiseau" désigne ici un personnage qui sort de l'ordinaire. On pourrait aussi dire par exemple "ce spécimen", "cet olibrius", "ce phénomène", "cet être exceptionnel"...

Comment: Ah oui ! Je comprends maintenant, merci beaucoup !